# como implementar un login con varias peticiones usando HttpClient o otra manera

Tags: angular, async-await

Me encuentro creando un login pero tengo un pequeño inconveniente
actualmente tenia un login jwt el clasico, pero ahora estamos implementando un login con pkce, este login hace 3 peticiones don un ejemplo

```
http://localhost:8000/codigiodesafio
http://localhost:8000/autorizacion
http://localhost:8000/token
```

esta 3 peticiones ejecutarla de manera asincrona, actualmente para mi login uso  HttpClient

comparto un codigo mi login actual

```
  //Service.ts
  public codigoDesafio(codigoDesafio: CodigoDesafio): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpCliente.post<any>(this.authURL+'/credenciales', codigoDesafio, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    });
  }


//lA PARTE DEL .TS
  inicioSesion() {
    if (this.login.valid) {
      this.codigoDesafio = new CodigoDesafio(
        this.login.value.email,
        this.login.value.password
      );


      this.loginService.codigoDesafio(this.codigoDesafio).subscribe({
       next: (data) => {

        },
      error:  (err) => {

        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Nota: me gustaría me oriente como poder ejecutar 3 rutas en un solo subcribe o si hay otra manera. Gracias....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias realizar  de la siguiente manera:

1. Creas un método donde tengas las peticiones a los 3 servicios (ej: getData())
2. Creas otro método con el subscribe para invocar a esos servicios. (ej: loadData())
3. Creas otro método para obtener las respuestas de las peticiones (ej: onLoadDependencies())

Te dejo el ejemplo aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]